# join() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Tags: python

I'm getting error with this code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 172, in grab_first_name
    f_name = ''.join(n.split()[0], '\n')
TypeError: join() takes exactly one argument (2 given)


f_name = ''.join(n.split()[0], '\n')
f.write(f_name)
print f_name
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're supplying two arguments to a function that expects one. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably you meant this:

```
'\n'.join(n.split()[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to say:

```
f_name = n.split()[0] + '\n'
```